# Server issues with apache and payara

Tags: apache-2.4

I am using apache as a proxy that redirects the traffic to a payara server. The issue I am experiencing is that when the server hits a traffic spike, it is slow to respond. I looked into our mpm_worker_module and here is the config:

```
<IfModule mpm_worker_module>
    ServerLimit              250
    StartServers             10
    MinSpareThreads          75
    MaxSpareThreads          250
    ThreadLimit              64
    ThreadsPerChild          32
    MaxRequestWorkers          8000
    MaxConnectionsPerChild  10000
</IfModule>
```

The numbers here seem very exaggerated and very wrong. I am no expert on apache and this is practically my first encounter with this sort of issue.

The apache server is running on 8GB ram which does not warrant the 8000 MaxRequestWorkers according to various posts here on stack.

The main issue is that the server becomes very unresponsive with about 50+ connected users. Any help and further information is very appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ServerLimit` value seems to be much too high.  The [apache documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/en/mod/mpm_common.html#serverlimit) says:

> Special care must be taken when using this directive. If ServerLimit
>   is set to a value much higher than necessary, extra, unused shared
>   memory will be allocated. If both ServerLimit and MaxRequestWorkers
>   are set to values higher than the system can handle, Apache httpd may
>   not start or the system may become unstable.

As a general recommendation `ServerLimit` should not be greater then the number of cpu cores of the server. This way you won't have more apache processes than you have cores to handle them.

`ThreadsPerChild`, which defines the maximum number of threads that a single apache process may spawn, looks okay, although you could try a higher value, e.g. 50 to get a better performance.

`MaxRequestWorkers` should not be greater then the product of `ServerLimit` and `ThreadsPerChild` which is btw. the case in the configuration above. With a `ServerLimit` of say 8 and 50 `ThreadsPerChild` it should be 400.

`MaxSpareThreads` and `MinSpareThreads` is set to the default value in that configuration, no need to change that. `MaxConnectionsPerChild` is okay, too.

So I would try to change these values:

```
ServerLimit              8
ThreadsPerChild          50
MaxRequestWorkers        400
```

and restart the apache service.

Comment: I have 4 cpu cores on the server should i still use 8 as the serverlimit? Does it seem to be logical that the server is slowing down when there are 50+ concurrent connections with out current config? Would it be wise to improve cpu cores and ram for our apache server to handle spikes?

Comment: Yes, I think that would still be okay because the process scheduler of your operating system will be able to handle cpu time for each of the 8 apache processes on the 4 cores. It was just a guess since you didn't mention how many cores you have.

Comment: Do you have any thoughts regarding my other questions? Does it seem to be logical that the server is slowing down when there are 50+ concurrent connections with out current config? Would it be wise to improve cpu cores and ram for our apache server to handle spikes?

Comment: Considering what the apache docs say it's quite probable that the server slows down significantly with that `ServerLimit`. and 4 cores and 8 GB RAM is a rather small hardware setup imo. But it's hard to tell without having access to the server.

Comment: Thanks alot, I will try this new config. Is there anyway I contact you if i have any further questions? or should i just revisit this thread?

Comment: Glad if I could help. Just come back here if there should be any issues, I'll get a notification than and have a look into it. Thanks!